# Generating Trees

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to generate valid trees given certain graph edges (which can be considered as a network). Following is the code which reads the graph edges from a file;

```
    FILE *fin = fopen("somefile.txt", "r");

    for (int i = 0; i <=edges; i++) {
    fscanf(fin, "%d%d%d", &u, &v, &w);
            graph[u][v]=w;
    }
    fclose(fin);
```

Now I want to generate the maximum number of possible trees (or topology) for a given root `u` and a given size `N` given these edges.

For example, if there are edges; 1--->2 ;1--->3; 3--->4. Now if N is 1; possible trees from u=1 is 1---->2 and 1--->3. If N is 2, then possible trees are 1--->2 & 3 or 1--->3---->4
What would be the best way of achieving this? I'm not concerned about complexity issues. I'll appreciate the help!

Comment: welll,i have tried using for loops but i'm running into a situation of having alot of for loops to generate a tree having N children. and its causing alot of confusion :(

Comment: What kind of for loops? We need to see how you're thinking about solving this problem before we can help you along the way.

Comment: to be quite honest, what i've done till now is not making much sense is is probably invalid. which is why im asking for any hints of a 'cleaner' or simple approach.

Comment: Problem statement needs clarification. You want to generate all directed trees, rooted in vertex u? Does every of the need to span the whole graph or they should have N size?

Comment: Yes, i need to generate directed trees which span N size. For example, if there are edges; 1--->2 ;1--->3; 3--->4. Now if N is 1; possible trees from u (1) is 1---->2 and 1--->3. If N is 2, then possible trees are 1--->2 & 3 or 1--->3---->4.

Comment: Are you comfortable with recursion?

Comment: im not sure as my knowledge of recursion always has been a little shaky. But if you have a solution in mind with recursion, i'll appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160160/generating-all-possible-trees-of-depth-n?rq=1 I found this link but can this be done in c++? But in this python program, the edges are bidirectional whereas we are talking about directional edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may not the best implementation but 
something like this should work

```
map<vertex,list<edge>> vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt
void Coloredge(edgeList)
{
  for each edge in list:
     edge.color=True
}


void init()
{
   for each edge:
   {
    vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt[edge.vertex1].append(edge)
    vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt[edge.vertex2].append(edge)
   }
}

edge* findUnColoredvertex(edgeList,startPoistion,founfAt)
{
    skip to startPoistion
    for each edge In edgeList:
          if edge not colored return edge 
    update founfAt
    return NULL
}

void spanTree(vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt,spanTreeList,lastvertex)
{
   if(spanTreeList.size==NumberOfTotalvertex)
   {
        print spanningTree
        return 
   }
   nextedge=findUnColoredvertex(vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt[lastvertex],0,founfAt)
   while(nextedge!=NULL)
   {           
       spanTreeList.append(nextedge);
       Coloredge(vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt[lastvertex]);
       spanTree(vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt,spanTreeList,nextedge.othervertex)
       spanTreeList.pop();
       UnColoredge(vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt[lastvertex])
       nextedge=findUnColoredvertex(vertexToedgeThatIncludeIt[lastvertex],founfAt,founfAt)
   }

 }
```

Comment: sorry for asking an elementary-level question, but how do i add edges? (i.e 1--->2; 3---->4).

Comment: im sorry , but im not an English speaker, i replaced edges with vertex

Comment: i tried to fixed it , no using auto find and replace , hope i didn't mess it up

Comment: if i got it right, this problem can't be solved using 2d array?

Comment: it is better you use a proper/natural  data structer and dont try to impose some synthetic data sturcter , STL let you define this easily

Comment: i have never used a vertex class. which header files to we need? PLus, is this a pseudo code or will it compile as it is?

Comment: its a pseudo  code, it wont compile . there is no such vertex class, you will need to create one by yourself. something like this struct vertex{int[2] edges,bool colored}

Comment: i still think that this problem can be solved with 2-d array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13049/discussion-between-jojo-and-amaar-bokhari)